# Need some advice on my own Role Based Access Control (RBAC)

Tags: .net, database, authorization, rbac

I have a pretty simple profile page where users can upload images and videos. I have implemented my own role system and I'm not using .NET (I wanted to learn and builded my own). I'll have 10´000 users at the most and about 50-100 users simultaneously using it.

I have three tables in the DB that handles my RBAC:

**Roles**: *Admin, User, Manager, Guest*
**Permissions**: *SendEmail, AdvancedSearch, RemoveUser*... etc.

**Authorized**: In this table I map a role to a permission. I run a check every time a permission is required for an action. If the permission<->role is in the table I return true and the action is authorized.

So, here's a few questions on this scenario.

- Is this a light weight way to check
  authorization? By quering the DB on
  every page load and action the user
  makes.
- Should I keep this in an XML-file for
  faster result?
- Is there a better structure for this
  sort of RBAC?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 50-100 users, I would just cache something per-active-user in the app. This avoids any small overhead from a db fetch, except for when it expires. So just have some small object that you can cache cheaply, but which includes all the user information you need to run the app's core functions.

Ther's nothing stopping you using this to implement an `IPrincipal` to use the inbuilt `[PrincipalPermission(...)]` stuff, but doing it yourself works too.

Comment: "except for when it expires"...that's why I didn't do it in the first place. But if this becomes the most popular answer I'll reconcider =)

Comment: @Niklas - querying once every few minutes is a lot better than querying every request...

Comment: So just to get this clear. When a user logs in I create a session variable storing every "permission" that user is allowed to make based on its' role. Like an array with strings?

Comment: @Niklas - not quite when they log on; rather, whenever you check the cache (based on however you handle identity) and it isn't there: create it and cache it.

Comment: Last one, then I'll stop bothering :P Could you give me a link on how to check the cache like you said. Also, I'm using User.Identity.Name already so a link on how to extend that to using roles =) Big thanks!

Comment: @Niklas - Any cache implementation should work - just create a unique key from what you already know (i.e. whatever you are usin gin your ticket/cookie/whatever), for example "usr_123455". The asp.net cache would be fine, as would a (correctly synchronized) dictionary

Comment: Ok, a last one =) I've cached an array with roles->permissions. Is there a place to keep the role of the logged in user in another place than a session or a cookie? Or did you mean that the cache would be a good place to keep the role of the logged in user aswell? Wouldn't this grow too large if I had 100 concurrent users?

Comment: @Niklas 100 users is **absolutely nothing**. Keep in mind that sites like stackoverflow run on top of ASP.NET... So no, that won't be too large at all, unless each user record somehow takes a few MB.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the answers to your questions.

•   Is this a light weight way to check authorization? By quering the DB on every page load and action the user makes.

*Ans*.  I would apply configurable caching system layer on database, and use this cache system for authorizations with customizable expiration time.

•   Should I keep this in an XML-file for faster result?

*Ans*. I would not prefer xml file, instead use serialization.

•   Is there a better structure for this sort of RBAC?

*Ans*. As far as the structure of the DB and RBAC is concerned, it should be secure enough that, access controls or permissions for applications cannot be directly tempered from DB.