# Need advice on user role based design

Tags: java, database-design, struts2

Let say I'm building an Q&A site like stackoverflow. My site has the following main features:

**Post**: post can be question or answer

**Profile**: personal profile of users

**Private Message**: stores private message of users

....

I was trying to figure out how to design user roles in my system.
And I came up with:
(each user only belongs to one role)

[image]

Is it ok to design user roles like this? If not, can anyone give me some suggestion?
I am using MySQL, Struts 2. In Struts 2, are there any avalable libraries for Role Based Access Control (RBAC)?

(I have read [Need some advice on my own Role Based Access Control (RBAC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115504/need-some-advice-on-my-own-role-based-access-control-rbac), but doesn't seem to solve my problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented RBAC in my current struts2-project.`RBAC` contains 3 things. User,Roles and Permissions.

Relationships are as below:

```
Role-Permission: M-M
User-Role:M-M
```

See, the relationship is like this because, If suppose you define a role ADMINISTRATOR, then it will require PERMISSIONS like CAN_READ,CAN_WRITE,CAN_EXECUTE...etc. You would also want to define Roles having combinations of above permissions and you would also like to create users with some combination of roles.
ex:

```
    READER is role having permission CAN_READ.
    WRITER is role having permission CAN_WRITE.
    You can now have user with role READER & WRITER
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think with that design, if user A belongs to role Mode which has edit permission, then user A will have edit permission on the whole system. In my system, user A may have edit permission on function A, but can only read permission on function B.

Comment: Then you need to define your permissions in that way Read_Fun_A,Write_Fun_A..Read_Fun_B,Write_Fun_B and assign roles accordingly:). See on a wider, extensible scope above relation fits fine. I have implemented it in my current project which is an enterprise system and has many role based scenarios.